# How to prevent xlswrite to overwrite the present values in an excel sheet?

Tags: matlab

I have some variables which need to get copied in an excel sheet. The variables gets changed every time I execute the program.Now when I try it with the XLSWRITE it over writes the previous value, but I need to retain the previous value and need to store the new value after the previous or old value in a specific column. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to count the numbers of executions by a variable N (either put a loop around your program or increase it manually).

Then you can [use](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/71504-convert-an-array-of-numbers-into-letters-1-a-2-b-3-c-etc) [something like](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/exporting-to-excel-spreadsheets.html) (assuming your data are in a vector):

```
N = 1;
data = 1:5;
filename = 'testdata.xlsx';

%% Horizontal
xlswrite(filename,data,1,['A',num2str(N)])

%% Vertical
% Alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
% letter = Alphabet(N);
% xlswrite(filename,data',1,[letter,'1'])
```

Comment: Thanks David. It was helpful.